# cat with output of sed

Tags: unix, sed, cat

I'd like to delete all lines starting with `##` in a file (`file.a`) and replace them with all the lines of another file (`file.b`). The lines to be deleted from `file.a` appear first in that file (there are no lines preceding them).

The long way would be:

```
sed -i '/##/d' file.a
cat file.b file.a > file.c
mv file.c file.a
```

Is there a short (in line) way?

Comment: If `file.a` has 2 rows starting with `##` and `file.b` has total `10` rows, then you want to remove `2` rows from `file.a` and append all `10` rows of `file.b` to `file.a`??

Comment: In a way. You can say I'd like to delete all n first rows from file.a (starting with "##") and append file.b to file.a. I don't know what n is aprior, although grep "##" file.a | wc -l will solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example files `file.a`

```
## line
## line
## line
linea1
linea2
linea3
```

and `file.b`

```
lineb1
lineb2
lineb3
```

This should do it:

```
$ sed -e '1r file.b' -e'/^##/d' file.a
lineb1
lineb2
lineb3
linea1
linea2
linea3
```

The `r filename` command inserts a file on line 1, and the second command removes all the lines starting with `##`. They have to be in separate `-e` expressions because after the filename there has to be a newline or the end of a command, so this would work as well:

```
sed '1r file.b
/^##/d' file.a
```

For in-place modification of `file.a`, the command becomes

```
sed -i -e '1r file.b' -e'/^##/d' file.a
```

Notice that the order of commands is significant: a delete command (`d`) starts a new cycle, and any command that comes after it is skipped, so `r` *has* to go first. <sub>Hat-tip: [potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong)</sub>

Comment: N.B. any commands following a `d` command will not be executed because it deletes the pattern space and begins a [new cycle](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands). Thus the commands must be in the above order and not visa versa.

Comment: @potong I'll go ahead and say that I was aware of that ;) Let me point it out explicitly.